# Catch function name passed in as argument to a function, for different handling?

Tags: r, function, parameter-passing

Suppose I have a function: `fun1 <- function(x, fun2) { # do something }` where `x` is a vector and `fun2` is a name of a function.

How can I test the `fun2` name within the function? For example if `fun2` is "mean", then I want to return a vector, if `fun2` is "summary" I want to return a list.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this using `match.arg`?

```
custom_function <- function(x) return(cat(sprintf("%05.4f\n", x)));

fun1 <- function(x, fun2 = c("mean", "summary", "custom_function")) {
    fun2 <- match.arg(fun2);
    if (fun2 == "mean") return(mean(x));
    if (fun2 == "summary") return(summary(x));
    if (fun2 == "custom_function") return(custom_function(x));
}

fun1(c(1,2,3), "mean");
[1] 2
fun1(c(1,2,3), "summary");
#Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.
# 1.0     1.5     2.0     2.0     2.5     3.0
fun1(c(1,2,3), "custom");
#1.0000
# 2.0000
# 3.0000
```

`arg.match` has the nice property that it also matches partial arguments. For example `fun1(c(1,2,3), "sum")` will also return the `summary`.

Comment: what if we pass a user defined function to fun2

Comment: This doesn't really need `match.arg` at all, that's just there to do validation.

Comment: @HongOoi Agreed. Still allows for more flexibility with matching arguments. But indeed you could omit the line `fun2 <- match.arg(fun2)`.